# Can't connect to or search Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, macbook

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu; I think it was 13 or something. Anyway, I got it running, and now I've been trying to connect to my Wi-Fi [AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point). No matter where I go I don't see an option for Wi-Fi.

I looked on the computer and found some commands to use in a terminal to run a scan for Wi-Fi networks, but all of them returned the error:

> interface doesn't support scanning

What are step-by-step directions to make this work?

Comment: I went to "additional drivers" and there are none listed. What does that mean I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a proprietary driver for your Wi-Fi device. Its usage is disabled by default.

You can enable proprietary drivers in [Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center), *Software Center* -> *Settings* -> *Configure software sources* -> checkbox *Proprietary drivers for devices*.

Then check for priprietary drivers available for your machine:

Open *Additional Drivers* either through *Systems Settings* or by clicking the Unity dash icon and entering "additional drivers".

You can find additional information about Wi-Fi networking in *[WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/)*.